# Modifying collections in foreach loop

Tags: c#, reference, pass-by-reference

Quick question:

```
public void ChangeObject(MyClass a){
  a.property = 55;
}

public void Test(){
  List<MyClass> obj_list = get_the_list();
  foreach( MyClass obj in obj_list )
  {
      ChangeObject(obj);
  }
}
```

Will this make all the values in obj_list have the property 55?

So somewhere else in my code I will call "if(obj_list[5].property == 55){ print("YES"); }" would be true after the loop.

Or do I need "ref"? Because it gives a lot of errors if you try to use ref (as you cannot modify iteration values).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Will this make all the values in obj_list have the property 55?

Yes - assuming `MyClass` really is a class. Imagine that the list is really an addressbook - there's the address of a house on every page (element). The list doesn't contain the actual houses themselves - just a way of getting to them. Your `foreach` loop is like saying, "For each page in the book, go to the house whose address is listed on the page and write 55 on the front door."

> Or do I need "ref"?

No. That would try to pass the *variable* by reference... and the iteration variable is readonly. See my article on [parameter passing in C#](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) for more details on this.

Comment: Yes that is what I hoped for. I guess because in C++ I'm use to the local variable in the loop NOT being a pointer to the full-collection (so it works differently).

Comment: be aware of `assuming MyClass really is a class` part. If your type is a value type (i.e. a struct) then your sample won't work with or without `ref`.

Comment: @ZdeslavVojkovic: It wouldn't work even *with* `ref` without extra work though. You'd have to iterate via the index, and replace the element in the list with the new value.

Comment: Exactly my point, that's why i added the comment, as it seemed to me that the OP was not aware of that